# currentCategoryId = currentId variable int?

Tags: int, nopcommerce

Using Nop Commerce I need to change the category navigation to get childsiblingsonly.

A parent category has a categoryID and a ParentCategoryID of 0. A child category has a categoryID and is mapped to the ParentCategoryID with its own CategoryId as seen in the example below.

```
ID PCID NAME 
10  0   Computers 
11  10  Software 
12  10  Hardware
13  0   Football
14  13  Tottenham
15  15  Manchester United
```

There are two methods in the catalog controller a Non Action and Public Action seen below. When I navigate to the product from the child category the navigation view disappears but I would like it to remain on the currentCategory Id the product are connected to if makes sense.

```
[NonAction]
    private IList<CategoryNavigationModel> GetOnlySiblings(Category currentCategory) 
    { 
        var result = new List<CategoryNavigationModel>();
        int Id = 0;
        if (currentCategory != null)
            Id = currentCategory.Id;

        foreach (var category in _categoryService.GetAllCategoriesByParentCategoryId(Id)) 
        {
            var model = new CategoryNavigationModel()
            {
                Id = category.Id,
                Name = category.GetLocalized(x => x.Name),
                SeName = category.GetSeName(),
                IsActive = currentCategory != null && currentCategory.Id == category.ParentCategoryId,
                NumberOfParentCategories = 0,
            };

            result.Add(model); 
        } 
        return result; 
    }
```

and the public action

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    //[OutputCache(Duration = 120, VaryByCustom = "WorkingLanguage")]
    public ActionResult CategoryNavigation(int currentCategoryId, int currentProductId)
    {
        string cacheKey = string.Format(ModelCacheEventConsumer.CATEGORY_NAVIGATION_MODEL_KEY, currentCategoryId, currentProductId, _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id);
        var cacheModel = _cacheManager.Get(cacheKey, () =>
        {
            var currentCategory = _categoryService.GetCategoryById(currentCategoryId);
            if (currentCategory == null && currentProductId > 0)
            {
                var productCategories = _categoryService.GetProductCategoriesByProductId(currentProductId);
                if (productCategories.Count > 0)
                    currentCategory = productCategories[0].Category;
            }
            var breadCrumb = currentCategory != null ? GetCategoryBreadCrumb(currentCategory) : new List<Category>();
            var model = GetOnlySiblings(currentCategory);
            return model;
        });

        return PartialView(cacheModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try reuse existing logic, something like this:

```
public IList<CategoryNavigationModel> GetOnlySiblings(int currentCategoryId)
        {
            var currentCategory = _categoryService.GetCategoryById(currentCategoryId);
            var siblingCategories = GetChildCategoryNavigationModel(new List<Category>(), currentCategory.ParentCategoryId, currentCategory, 0);

            return siblingCategories;
        }
```